# Excel used in testNG data provider is using old data even if new data is provided

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I am using dataprovider to read data from and excel as inputs to my selenium script. I am basically adding systems to my application. Earlier i had about 110 rows and 7 columns worth of data in the  excel. Now i have removed that and added 1 row and 7 columns worht of data in the same excel, but the script is still trying to add 110 systems. I am not understanding why this is happening.

This is the dataprovider:

```
  @DataProvider (name= "systemData")
  public static Object[][] systemData() throws IOException
  {
      Object Data[][] = ExcelUtils.readData("D:\\Eclipse O\\Data\\addSystem\\AddSystem.xlsx", "AddSystem");
      return Data;
  }

}
```

And this is the excel util

```
package Utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExcelUtils
{
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    static XSSFSheet sheet;
    static XSSFCell cell;

     @Test
     public static Object[][] readData(String sheetLocation, String sheetName) throws IOException
     {
         DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
         // Import excel sheet.
         File src=new File(sheetLocation);

         // Load the file.
         FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(src);

         // Load the workbook.
         workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(finput);

         // Load the sheet  in which data is stored.
         sheet= workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
         int RowNum = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();// count my number of Rows
         System.out.println("Number of rows is " +RowNum);

         int ColNum = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
         System.out.println("Number of columns is " +ColNum);

         String Data[][]= new String[RowNum][ColNum];

         for (int i = 0; i < RowNum; i++) 
            {
             //System.out.println("First for loop entered");   
             XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < ColNum; j++) 

                {
                    //System.out.println("Second for loop entered");
                    if (row == null) {
                        Data[i][j] = "";
                    System.out.println("row = null entered");
                    }
                    else {
                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);                 
                        if (cell == null) {
                            Data[i][j] = ""; 
                        System.out.println("Cell = null entered");
                        }
                        else {
                            String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                            Data[i][j] = value.trim();                        
                        }
                    }


                }
                }       
                return Data;
          } 
    }
```

Comment: Kindly refresh the project.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I tried refreshing. Its still causing same issue

Comment: I have added my code in the description.

Comment: are you using any version control ?

Comment: are you running script on your local machine ?

Comment: Make sure you are passing correct sheet name

Comment: Yes am running on my local machine and am passing the correct sheet name as well.. It adds the new system in the sheet however it tries to add 110 other systems as well that were in the excel sheet before.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart if using Intellij. Save the excel file, remove it from source and add again. Give it a try.